# How to edit a number which is at a specific location in a given file in C?

Tags: c, file, gcc

I have saved a list of number as

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

in the file `INPUT.txt`. and I want to edit a specific location (which is the 5th element here) and want to replace it by number `35`. How can I do this? (I do not want to create another new file, neither I want to overwrite the whole thing, just editing that file only!!).

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void main() { 
    FILE *fp; 
    char ch; 
    int a, i, b = 35;
    fp = fopen("INPUT.txt", "r+");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &a);
        printf("\t%d\n", a);
        if (i == 5) {
            fprintf(fp, "b");
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);  
}
```

Comment: If you are simply storing numbers, you could reserve x bytes per entry in the file (x depends on the range obv.), and just store them as data rather than in a human-readable representation. This way, modifying them becomes a trivial task and is left as homework for the reader.

Comment: The representation of "35" is bigger than that of "5". It won't fit in the same space no matter what you want. If you were using a special file format with a fancy  internal structure it might accommodate it. With a plain old text file - you can't have what you want. The closest you might come would be rewriting/overwriting the rest of the file following your change. Now if you wanted to replace "5" with "8", that you could do.

Comment: @vmt's suggestion of a binary file would work as long as you are only accessing it from programs using the same binary format. Another similar option keeping it as a text file would be to represent each number with enough leading zeros/spaces so that the representations were all the same length.

Comment: @AviBerger how to do that? to edit with a number which have same space?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica no! i made a mistake.

Comment: +1 to the leading zeroes solution. The file will still be _readable_, and their printed version will not change. Btw: that `fprintf ()` will NOT write the value of variable b in the desired location, but only the letter `'b'`.

Comment: @SaptarshiBiswas the way to "edit with a number which have same space", as you're using fopen, you'd just move the stream position indicator to the position of the target in the file with fseek, and then overwrite it using fwrite.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this reliably by modifying the text file in place with the stream functions because you need to insert characters. You should make a modified copy of the file, then remove the original file, or rename it as a backup, and rename the new file to the original name.

Alternately, you could read the whole file in memory, perform the modification and rewrite the new contents to the file.